# SP MetaData generation for SAML - Need clarification on X509 tags

Tags: java, metadata, x509certificate, saml-2.0

I am new to SAML. I did lot of research and right now pretty much clear on how the whole flow works. But stuck with Metadata file generation on SP side.

I read some articles and wrote a working code for generating metadata file. But what I don't understand is the certificate part in the metadata. As I am on the SP side, I should be using the public key which should be used by the IDP for encryption. But, when I saw the logic for Metadata generation (in many different sites) , the certificate append logic is as below :

```
        //Fetch the private key certificate and pass it to the below method.
 This method's Java doc for SecurityHelper.getSimpleCredential method says 
"Get a simple, minimal credential containing an end-entity X.509 certificate, and optionally a private key. "

     SecurityHelper.getSimpleCredential(x509Certificate, privateKey);
                    try {
            //Add it to the signing descriptor of metadata    
            signingKeyDescriptor.setKeyInfo(keyInfoGenerator.generate(difiCredential.toX509Credential()));
                        } catch (SecurityException e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage()+ e);
                        }

        spSPSSODescriptor.getKeyDescriptors().add(signingKeyDescriptor);
```

1. What does this method do? Does it generate public key and append to my metadata?
2. If not, Why are we appending private key to SP's metadata which would be shared to my IDP's who does not need it at all? Shouldn't I be sharing my public key which can be used by them for encryption? And later I would use my private key internally to decrypt it?

I want to be very sure before I generate my metadata as it has security implications.

Thanks.